# VBA Data Type within another Data Type

Tags: vba, types

I am trying to us a Type within another type but it is not letting me.

```
Public Type MyTable
     Name As String
     IDStartingNumber As Integer
     Items(50) As MyItem
End Type

Public Type MyItem
    Name As String
    DataType As DataTypes
    Number As Integer
    AllowNull As Boolean
    Unique As Boolean
    Reference As MyTable
End Type
```

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Compile Error: Forward reference to  user-defined type"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the type you're referencing is before it.  In your example you have the MyItem type afterwards.  For example:

```
Public Type MyItem
    Name As String
    DataType As DataTypes
    Number As Integer
    AllowNull As Boolean
    Unique As Boolean
    Reference As MyTable
End Type

Public Type MyTable
     Name As String
     IDStartingNumber As Integer
     Items(50) As MyItem
End Type
```

Answer (score 0):

In both examples, it appears one type references the other, so neither example should work.

i.e.

Public Type MyTable
     Name As String
     IDStartingNumber As Integer
     Items(50) As **MyItem**
End Type

Public Type MyItem
    Name As String
    DataType As DataTypes
    Number As Integer
    AllowNull As Boolean
    Unique As Boolean
    Reference As **MyTable**
End Type

You cannot have one type refer to a different type which refers back to the first type.